# How can I migrate my Tezos baking address to Ledger Nano?

Tags: node, ledger, tezos-client

I have a running baking server and want to upgrade my signer setup to use a Ledger Nano S.

Per default the Nano S creates it's own seed and addresses, but I want to keep the delegators and baking history of my current address.

How can I migrate my Tezos baking private keys to the Nano S?

I have tried initializing a fresh Nano S, installed the Ledger Tezos app on it and linked it to a fresh TezBox installation. I can't find any option to import a private key to the Nano S.

Comment: Importing your wallet to the Ledger wouldn't suffice?

Comment: How can I do that? I've initialized my Nano S and linked it in TezBox-Wallet. But I can't find anywhere to import my baker address to the Nano S.

Comment: It might be software-specific. For instance, [this official guide](https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/getting-started-with-tezos-on-the-ledger-nano-s-c011517b0f3c) only explicitly suggests you can import a wallet with Magnum Wallet. I don't know if TezBox or Galleon can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible and for a very good reason:

The whole purpose of ledger is to protect the secret key of the addresses it manages in its [secure element](https://www.ledger.fr/2018/12/03/a-closer-look-into-ledger-security-the-secure-element/) so that no one can access it.

If you could “import” a secret key that you can have access to then by definition it would mean that this secret key may have been compromised already so there would be no security benefit in using a ledger to manage it

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk sorry what is the relationship with the original question ?

Answer (score 1):

Soon, hopefully. Enhanced baking accounts are in the pipeline and currently under discussion. Hodl. See ["1. Inability to Update or Change Accounts"](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/enhancing-baking-accounts/1627)